# Merge/join a dataframe based on nearest datetime to different dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of a pretty high length (100,000+), and I want to merge this dataframe with another based on closest element (by index) to a different dataframe object. For example, let us say that object 1 is the following:

```
 DateTime                x_1   y_1
 2016-07-05 08:30:00     1     2
 2016-07-05 08:30:01     3     4 
 2016-07-05 08:30:02     5     6
 2016-07-05 08:30:03     7     8
 2016-07-05 08:30:05     9     10
 2016-07-05 08:30:11     11    12
```

and object 2 is the following:

```
 DateTime                x_2   y_2
 2016-07-05 08:30:00     13    14
 2016-07-05 08:30:05     15    16
 2016-07-05 08:30:05     17    18
 2016-07-05 08:30:10     19    20
```

I want to return a new object, object3, which has the same length as object2, and now contains items from object1 which are closest to the times of object2. Object3, in this case, would look like this:

```
 DateTime                x_2   y_2   x_1   y_1  
 2016-07-05 08:30:00     13    14    1     2
 2016-07-05 08:30:05     15    16    9     10
 2016-07-05 08:30:05     17    18    9     10
 2016-07-05 08:30:10     19    20    11    12
```

I currently do something along these lines to get this to work, but I get reindex errors (non-unique index):

`object3 = object2.join(object1.reindex(object2.index, method='nearest'), how='left')`

which returns a valueerror:

`ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit`

Comment: The many-to-one example you provided happen to merge on date time that is the same.  Was that intentional?  If not, can you provide an example of what "close" means and how you'd want it handled?

Comment: @unutbu: yes! Sorry, it was intended to be 2016-06-05 08:30:10

Comment: @piRSquared: yes! this was intentional. i wanted duplicates of the index to be retained

Comment: What I meant was, is this a simple merge on equal values or do you need some fuzzy matching of datetimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `reindex` on the unique values of the other index.  You'll pick up the duplicates during the join.

```
object3 = object2.join(object1.reindex(object2.index.unique(), method='nearest'))
```

The resulting output:

```
                     x_2  y_2  x_1  y_1
DateTime                               
2016-07-05 08:30:00   13   14    1    2
2016-07-05 08:30:05   15   16    9   10
2016-07-05 08:30:05   17   18    9   10
2016-07-05 08:30:10   19   20   11   12
```